# VBA Date 31/12/1899

Tags: vba, excel, date, dictionary

I'm reading in data from a spreadsheet into a dictionary but having problems with a date field.

The code that reads in the data is

```
sourceworkbook.setRangeSingleCell "Review date(1)", cell.Row
dictionaryObject.ReviewDate = sourceworkbook.range.Value
```

This sets the range to the cell I want based on the column header and then grabs the value before putting it into the dictionary. Reviewdate is defined as a string inside a class.

I then do nothing with this particular field and just dump it back out from the dictionary to a different spreadsheet as follows:

```
targetWorkbook.setRangeSingleCell "Review Date", foundRowNumber
targetWorkbook.range.Value = Dictionary.Item(Key).ReviewDate
```

However, whilst this works fine with some dates, some show as 31/12/1899, Looking at my current dump I have a date of 18/07/2016 that has worked fine, but a date of 28/06/2016 has not.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: have you tried to set a break point if the value is 0? Dates are just numerical values which is 0 for 31/12/1899... this pretty much shows that something returns nothing

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I added a breakpoint and there was an issue elsewhere in the code that was causing this paticular field to get wiped between me adding it to a dictionary and then dumping it out onto a different spreadsheet.